# osCommerce Stuck Step 1. The database structure is now being imported. Please be patient during this procedure

Tags: oscommerce

I'm trying to install osCommerce. I tried to install 2.3.3.4 and 3.0.2 versions, however I got stucked in step 1. The message below is shown and don't pass through the next step.

```
The database structure is now being imported. Please be patient during this procedure.
```

It ran over 6 hours without conclusion the step. Of course it is not to be patient.

The server recommendations are green. I mean, OK!

I tried install with IE, FF and Chrome.

I executed the SQL command below on MySQL and I could verify some progress, but as I said: The message is shown and don't pass through the next step.

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", 
SUM( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

Product versions are:
W32 (test environment)
PHP 5.4
MySQL 5.6.14
osCommerce 2.3.3.4 or 3.0.2
IE 9
FF 25.0.1
Chrome 31.0.1650

Could you please help me?

Comment: below you can see that tables are being loaded, but something went wrong:
SELECT TABLE_NAME, table_rows,
round(((data_length+index_length)/1024 1024),2) "Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = "ecommerce"
ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC
LIMIT 5;
+---------------------------+------------+------------+
| TABLE_NAME                | table_rows | Size in MB |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+
| osc_zones                 |       4256 |       0.36 |
| osc_languages_definitions |        697 |       0.14 |
+---------------------------+------------+------------+

Comment: Are You sure that You are using database which exist and it's empty?
Have You entered correct login details, have You tested them?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem yesterday. Here some steps how I made it actually work:

1. When you hit "Continue" button on Step 1 screen, installation module actually creates tables in mysql database. You can verify them by console or phpmyadmin (if you have it installed). It creates about 50 tables and then stops for some reason.
2. After you assure that all 50 tables are present, you can continue to step 2 by modifying your URL. It should look like this: 
    http://example.com/install/install.php?step=2 
    All other steps will go smoothly.
3. When you reach step 4, installation file will rewrite your files: /include/configure.php and /admin/include/configure.php and set them 644 permissions (which lately must be changed to 444 by hands). You need to modify them further, because they doesn't contain information about your database (guess it should be modified by step 1, but whatever). So open it in editor and modify lines:

   `define('DB_SERVER', 'your server');
   define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'your username');
   define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'your password');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'your database name');`
4. Open http://example.com/admin/ 
   Note that it will complain about "No admin user installed (though it must be there by success of step 3...). But anyway, just create new admin user and you will get the access to your admin panel.

No problems spotted so far, so i assume this can be some kind of solution. Especially if you don't want to mess with the code.